# Is the function $(x,y) \mapsto \frac{x}{y}$ convex in the region $x,y>0$?

Tags: convex-analysis

Is the function $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}$ convex in the region $x, y > 0$?

I think the Hessian matrix is not positive semidefinite and the function is not convex as well:

\begin{equation}
 H =\begin{bmatrix}
0   &   -\frac{1}{y^2} \\
 -\frac{1}{y^2}   &    \frac{2x}{y^3}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are.___

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the relation between convexity and positive semi-definite Hessian Matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2193810/what-is-the-relation-between-convexity-and-positive-semi-definite-hessian-matrix)